# Makor2 problem in texlive 2022

Tags: texlive

I have installed texlive 2022 and would like to write Hebrew using Makor2. For this you need to install the Omega extension. My attempts failed. How do I install the Omega and Makor2 extension on texlive 2022?

Comment: omega is obsolete https://ctan.org/pkg/omega. Can't you use lualatex or xelatex?

Comment: You're right, but makor2 allows you to write in different languages using the Latin script. You don't need to use letters like Hebrew. As far as I know, xelatex and lualatex need to be written in Hebrew, Arabic etc.

Comment: transliterations are possible with lualatex (and xelatex) too, see e.g. the arabluatex package. The babel documentation contains a list of existing transliterations (but imho nothing for hebrew yet).